# QGIS Automatically Generate Atlas for each Column on the Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, batch, atlas

I want to generate graduated maps in QGIS (using the same style) for each of the columns on the attribute table. Every columns contains the data of one year.

It seems that the Atlas only automatically create maps for each row, it there any way to do it for the columns instead? I saw in another post that says it could be done by transpose, but how to I keep the graduated styles that's applied to each column?

---

My table look like this:

State          year1        year2       year3

state1         222          222         222

state2         333          333          333

state3         444          444          444